# Regular expression in htaccess issue

Tags: regex, .htaccess, uri, expression

i would like to use a short url in my sub domain but I have a problem. It actually works fine in my local host, but when I put it in my subdomain of my online host, it doesn't work. My subdomain is like this : **str.example.com.** So the short url is like : **str.example.com/h4g784**

My real address that is going to read is  : **str.example.com/url.php?url=h4g784**

**Bellow is my htaccess :**

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(\w+)$ ./url.php?url=$1   
RewriteRule ^([^\.]+)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

I don't know why do I get 500 Internal Server Error. 
I really appreciate for your time to look at my code.

Comment: have you tried without the `./` on `./index.php`?

Comment: What exactly is the second rule doing? It looks like the first one would do what you want...

Comment: fyi you don't need to escape within a character class, so `[^\.]` can be coded as `[^.]`